# Filter related entities or navigation property where there is a join table in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-6

I have three entities `Role`, `RoleUser` and `User`

I want to select each Compulsory `Role` and load the related `User`'s where the `RoleUser.RecordID` in the join table is equal to a given value.

Using the UOW and GenericReposiity `Get(...)` method I would call ...

`.Get(role => role.Compulsory == true, null, "RoleUser.User")` to select all the compulsory role's and load all `User` for the navigation `RoleUser.User`.

How can I filter them, is it possible using the implemented `Get()` method?

**Entities**

```
    public class Role
    {
        public int RoleID { get; set; }

        public bool Compulsory { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<RoleUser> RoleUser { get; set; }       
    }


    public class RoleUser
    {
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }


        public Guid RecordID { get; set; }

        public virtual Record Record { get; set; }


        public int RoleID { get; set; }

        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }


    public class User
    {
        public string userID { get; set; }
    }
```

**Get**

```
    public virtual IList<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No , you cant filter the `RoleUser` from this Get method. if you want to filter `RoleUser` you want to project them into another list.
>
> You can filter your `Role` based on the `RoleUser` table.
>
> Include will always bring full data in the table unless you use IQuerable Projection.

```
var rolesWithAnyUserName = UnitOfWork.Role
                                     .Get(role => role.Compulsory == true && role.RoleUser
                                   .Any(g=>g.RoleUserName=="Name"), null, "RoleUser.User")
```

**This will only filter the `Role` based on the `RoleUser` filter**

If you need to filter `Include` tables write the query where you can send `IQuerable` to the database

Try something like this , this will filter both `Role` and `RoleUser`

```
var result = DataContext.Role.Where(role => role.Compulsory == true )
                .Include(gl => gl.RoleUser)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    role = x,
                    roleUsers= x.RoleUser.Where(g => g.Id == 1),
                }).ToList();
```